# Subclass of PyTorch dataset class cannot find dataset files

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, pytorch, subclass

I'm trying to create a subclass of the PyTorch MNIST dataset class, which I call  `CustomMNISTDataset`, as follows:

```
import torchvision.datasets as datasets

class CustomMNISTDataset(datasets.MNIST):

    def __init__(self, root='/home/psando'):
        super().__init__(root=root,
                         download=False)
```

but when I execute:

```
dataset = CustomMNISTDataset()
```

it fails with error: "RuntimeError: Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it".

However, when I run the following in the same file:

```
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='/home/psando', download=False)
print(len(dataset))
```

**it succeeds** and prints "60000", as expected.

Since `CustomMNISTDataset` subclasses `datasets.MNIST` **why is the behavior different?** I've verified that the path '/home/psando' contains the MNIST directory with raw and processed subdirectories (otherwise, explicitly calling the constructor for `datasets.MNIST()` would have failed). The current behavior implies that the call to `super().__init__()` within `CustomMNISTDataset` is not calling the constructor for `datasets.MNIST` which is very strange!

Other details: I'm using Python 3.6.8 with `torch==1.6.0` and
`torchvision==0.7.0`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try ```download='True'```?

Comment: According to docs, `download` is supposed to be a bool, not a string. But let me make `download=True` in `CustomMNISTDataset ` to see where it places the downloaded files...

Comment: It works even with download = "True"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires some source-diving, but your problem is [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/37eb37a836fbc2c26197dfaf76d2a3f4f39f15df/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L145) function. The path to the dataset is dependant on the name of the class, so when you subclass `MNIST` the root folder changes to `/home/psando/CustomMNISTDataset`

So if you rename `/home/psando/MNIST` to `/home/psando/CustomMNISTDataset` it works.

Comment: I see! Yes, I just now changed `download=True` in `CustomMNISTDataset` and I noticed it was downloading to `/home/psando/CustomMNISTDataset`. I was under the impression it would always be looking for the `MNIST/` directory within the root directory passed as a parameter. Thanks for linking the relevant line in the source code!

Comment: So is subclassing a dataset class in this way discouraged?

Comment: Not really, it just means that the `root` parameter wasn't exactly what you expected it to be. Just keep the naming in mind, so you don't end up with a bunch of copies of the dataset :)